# Changing application name and packages

Tags: android, eclipse

I decided to change the name of my app.  I updated all references to the app including references in the Manifest, the project, the package names, etc.

If I grep the application's directory, all references to the old name are gone.

However, when I compile my application and send it to the emulator, the bottom right corner of Eclipse reads, "Launching OldAppName."

How do I fix this?  Obviously, there is a reference lingering around somewhere.

Comment: Did you check the strings.xml files? The app name is often stored there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit Run/Debug entry name in project settings